# CRON Job not working on meteor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, cron

In main.js in server folder,
I have this code,

```
var DDP = require('ddp');
var DDPlogin = require('ddp-login');
var Job = require('meteor-job');
var ddp = new DDP({
  host: "127.0.0.1",
  port: 3000,
  use_ejson: true
});
Meteor.startup(() => {
var myJobs = JobCollection('myJobQueue');
Job.setDDP(ddp);
ddp.connect(function (err) {
    if(err) throw err;
    DDPlogin(ddp, function (err, token) {
        if (err) throw err;
    });
});
myJobs.allow({
    admin: function (userId, method, params) {
      return true;
    }
});
Meteor.publish('allJobs', function () {
  return myJobs.find({});
});
myJobs.startJobServer();
var workers = Job.processJobs('myJobQueue', 'sendEmail',
    function (job, cb) {
        console.log(job.data.text);
        job.done();
        cb(null);
    }
);
```

And in my main.js in client folder,
I have this code,

```
var myJobs = JobCollection('myJobQueue');
var jobSub = null;
class App extends Component {
    componentDidMount(){
        if(jobSub !== null)
            jobSub.stop();
        jobSub = Meteor.subscribe('allJobs');
        var job = new Job(myJobs, 'sendEmail',
            {
             text: 'bozo@clowns.com'
             }
        );
        job.priority('normal')
            .retry({ retries: 5,
              wait: 60*1000 })  // 1 minute between attempts
              .delay(0)     // start immediately
              .save();              
    }
    ...
    render(){
    console.log(myJobs.find().fetch());
        ...
    }
}
```

I am using the [vsivsi:meteor-job-collection](https://github.com/vsivsi/meteor-job-collection) package.

The problem is that console.log() is not executed.
What is wrong in my step by step installation and usage? 
I need to console.log() every minute.

Comment: Do you know for sure that `componentDidMount()` is executing? It looks like you took your code from the example code in the package but instead of running it at startup on the client you're running it inside a component. Also what is the purpose of putting the `console.log()` into your `render()`?

Comment: It is solved now. thanks. The solution I used for this is place the new Job statement to server main file.